# Probability of two unconnected graphs

Tags: probability, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices where each edge is chosen with probability $\frac{1}{2}$:
>
> - $G$ is separated, if we can divide the vertices of the graph into two equal-sized sets where there are no edges between them.
> - $G$ is almost-separated, if we can divide the vertices of the graph into two equal-sized sets where there are less than $10n$ edges between them.

1)What is the probability of G to be separated?

2)What is the probability of G to be almost-separated?

So far I have tried to calculate $\sum_{i=0}^n A_i$, Where $A_i$ is the probability of the cut $i$ to separate the graph. The problem is that $A_i$'s are dependent.

UPDATE: I thought about the problems as for each cut we have $\frac{{n}^{2}}{4}$ edges and we do not want anyone of them.
It's is the same as having a random variable $X\sim Bin(\frac{{n}^{2}}{4})$.

1) So for the first part what we are calculating is:$P(X=0)$
$$P(X=0)=\binom{\frac{{n}^{2}}{4}}{0}*{(\frac{1}{2}})^{0} *{(\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{{n}^{2}}{4}}={(\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{{n}^{2}}{4}}$$

2)In the second part, we are calculating: $P(X\leq10n)$
.Which I could not calculate.

Comment: Note that the question uses *separated* in an unusual sense

Comment: @Henry English is not my native language and I have translated the question to English. Which term would you suggest to use?

Comment: Which term does the original use?

Comment: @joriki It is a word in Hebrew, "מופרד" if you are interested.

Comment: @Adddison: Thanks – it so happens that I do speak Hebrew :-) Without the requirement that the two parts are of equal size, the term would be "disconnected", but I don't know a term for this specific form of disconnectedness – "symmetrically disconnected" would sort of fit.

Comment: In the update, the probability you're calculating is the probability that $G$ is "separated" by one particular cut. The question asks for the probability that $G$ is "separated" by *any* cut.

Comment: is not that the same as calculating for (# of cuts * probability of signal cut)/(# of cuts)=probabilty of signal cut?

Comment: I just read that by coincidence; if you want me to get notified you need to ping me with @joriki. Why are you dividing by the number of cuts?

Answer (score 2):

Solving this exactly seems hard. You could approximate it by the expected number of cuts,

$$
\frac12\binom n{\frac n2}2^{-\left(\frac n2\right)^2}\;.
$$

Since the probability for more than one cut decreases very rapidly with $n$, this is a good approximation alread for moderate $n$. If you want, you can calculate successive corrections with (increasingly complicated) [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) terms. For two cuts, we can divide the vertices into four sets $A\cap B$, $A\cap\overline B$, $\overline A\cap B$ and $\overline A\cap\overline B$ of sizes $k$, $\frac n2-k$, $\frac n2-k$ and $k$, respectively, with a total of

$$
k^2+\left(\frac n2-k\right)^2+4k\left(\frac n2-k\right)=\left(\frac n2\right)^2+kn-2k^2
$$

edges that must not exist, for a contribution of

$$
-\frac14\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{k!^2\left(\frac n2-k\right)!^2}2^{-\left(\frac n2\right)^2-kn+2k^2}
$$

(where a symmetry correction is required if $n$ is a multiple of $4$). For $n=6$ this is  $-\frac{45}{8192}\approx-0.0055$, compared to the main term $\frac5{256}\approx0.02$, and for $n=10$ it’s $-\frac{7875}{34359738368}\approx-2.3\cdot10^{-7}$, compared to the main term $\frac{63}{16777216}\approx3.8\cdot10^{-6}$.

Comment: I went in the same direction at first but it got complicated so I did not pursue it. I added a solution for the first part which I am not sure of but I think I am in the right direction now. The second part seems solvable now without approximation.